# QML Nested List View with separators

Tags: qt, gridview, treeview, qml

I'm trying to implement a tree view that represent structure of buildings/floors/rooms. All rooms should be classified by floor and building ( thus header for each building and floor is required.

First I implemented it with Repeater, Row and Grid elements. However i need a selection behaviour so i need to use ListView and GridView. However I have problems displaying nested list views.

Here's my code so far: http://pastie.org/private/3seqntgvskbyxnmnuluaua

Expected Result( when using Grid and Repeater instead of GridView and List View ):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it myself, but here is how to implementation a tree view in QML.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/632795/QML-TreeModel-and-TreeView

Answer (score 1):

There is still no official tree view component in Qt (as of version 5.2). However, see the solution provided by jens on this thread

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/30521

This is by far the best tree view that I have come across. It should provide a good basis for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes I saw this long time ago:) However the important part here was adding the separators, which cannot be easily done with the tutorial. Thanks anyway:)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Qt Company is releasing a QML TreeView in Qt5.5. Alpha release should be coming out in February.

http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/02/05/licensing-of-new-modules-in-qt-5-5/